# Configuring SSL on JBoss 7

Tags: java, ssl, jboss

I am trying to add SSL support for my JBoss 7 installation. I followed the directions for the pure java solution on: [JBoss AS 7.1 SSL Setup Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide?_sscc=t)

Here is my standalone.xml subsystem configuration

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" native="false" default-virtual-server="default-host">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"  redirect-port="443" />
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
    <connector name="https" scheme="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
        <ssl name="ps-ssl" password="mypw" protocol="TLSv1" key-alias="ps" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/ps.keystore" />
    </connector>
</subsystem>
```

When I start up the application, I get the firefox problem loading page message. I have configured web.xml to require https for the entire app. The application works fine when I remove the constraint, so I guess I missed something in setting up ssl. Does anybody see anything that I missed?

Comment: Starting the server from the command line and providing the stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: That's the thing, there really is no stack trace to speak of. I went back and changed the socket bindings to 80 and 443 for http and https, respectively, and that seemed to sort of fix it.